# Representing family relationships between Patients in FHIR

Tags: database-design, hl7-fhir

I need to represent a mother-child relationship between two [Patient](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/patient.html) records in FHIR. The [RelatedPerson](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/relatedperson.html) model seemed like the most obvious to use for this, but it does not permit linking two `Patient` records. `Patient.link` is only supposed to be used for linking multiple records that are for the exact same patient. How can I represent this relationship?

Comment: I'm new to FHIR, but could you use List or Group https://www.hl7.org/fhir/composition.html?

Comment: @BobSalmon: I was thinking about doing that, but I'm hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RelatedPerson is the way to go: You can create a [RelatedPerson](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/relatedperson.html) for the mother that points to the child, then create a [Person](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/person.html) for the mother, pointing to both the RelatedPerson and the Patient record for the mother. This can also be done the other way around (Person+RelatedPerson for the child).

Comment: How do I associate the RelatedPerson(mother) and the Person(mother)?

Comment: With Person.link you point to the RelatedPerson(mother) and to the Patient(mother), then from RelatedPerson.patient you reference the Patient(child).

Comment: OK, so you're saying that I use RelatedPerson as a join table? Therefore, `motherPerson.relatedPerson.patient = babyPerson`.

Comment: Yes, essentially correct, although the relatedPerson would be in motherPerson.link.target.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid way of representing this information, however would like to know a little more about your use case for recording this information.
Is it to be supporting maternity issues and the linkage of encounters for the mother and baby during a birth encounter. If so then the encounter.partof structure would be recommended for capturing the details of this association.

Comment: It will be used after birth, for tracking interactions that involve mother, baby, and practitioners. Is that enough information?

Comment: Within the context of the encounter (admission) or post admission?